# Warning message when using sudo

Tags: sudo, root

So I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and for some reason every time I use sudo or log in as root I get the following message:

```
grant@grant-G551JM:~$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
sudo: unable to resolve host grant-G551JM
[sudo] password for grant:
```

It still lets me proceed as if nothing happened, but I get it every time and want to amend the situation. Anyone have any clue as to why this would be?